# Variables overwriting text problem with "echo" in Bash

Tags: macos, bash, echo

I use OS X 10.6.5, Bash.

When I run this:

```
echo $IP; echo of; echo $IPLINES
```

I get this output:

```
219.80.4.150:3128
of
1108
```

When I run this:

```
echo $IP of $IPLINES
```

I get this output:

```
 of 1108.150:3128
```

I expected to get:

```
219.80.4.150:3128 of 1108
```

What would cause the distorted output I am getting?

The actual script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IPLINES=`cat a.txt | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ $IPLINES > 1 ]; then
    LINE=`expr $RANDOM % $IPLINES + 1`
    IP=`head -$LINE a.txt | tail -1`
    sed -e "${LINE}d" -i .b a.txt

    echo $IP of $IPLINES
fi
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A wild guess here: you are extracting the IP variable from a .txt file -- if that's a Windows file, or is encoded Windows-style, lines end with `\r\n`. You take the newline away, but what if there's a `\r` in it that's making you go back to the beginning of the line?

Quick dirty fix with no questions asked: use `echo -n`, it supresses the newline at the end of the echoed text.

```
echo -n $IP; echo -n of; echo -n $IPLINES
```

If the problem persists, it's probably what I said above. Try right-trimming `$IP`.

**EDIT: didn't see the OSX part, sorry. In OSX, lines end with `\r` -- that must be the issue.**

Comment: Right, and Right.  I changed line endings in my file, problem solved.  Thanks for -n, I was unfamiliar with that flag.

Comment: Actually in OS X, lines typically *don't* end with \r. You generally might only see that in files from old legacy apps from classic Mac OS days.

Comment: You can remove unwanted characters also using `tr`: `cleanline="$(echo $line | tr -d '\r')"`

Comment: `echo -n` is bad form -- see the [POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) which specifies its behavior as undefined, and -- in the APPLICATION USAGE section -- suggests using `printf` instead. (That is, `printf '%s' "$foo"` instead of `echo -n "$foo"`, or `printf '%b' "$foo"` instead of `echo -ne "$foo"`).

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that there is a carriage return (`\r`) at the end of `$IP`.